# why javascript is not functioning as expected after dividing the one html file into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the following theme. when the code for the following  output is saved in a single file everything(dropdown menu's of top header and left navigation bar's accordion style) is working perfectly.

[image]

When I have separated and divided the code into multiple files as top_header.php, left-nav.php, index.php and footer.php and included all the four php files into index.php, then dropdown menu's were not working.

I have added the ".js" files into all the files, drop downs were working perfectly(even though adding of files is redundant which is not good in practice).

But left navigation's accordion menu's are not working.

Comment: `I have added the ".js" files into all the files` this sounds like it could be your problem. You should only include each required JS file *once* in the page. Without more details of the code, we can't really help.

Comment: try placing all the css and js files in header.php .. and make sure jquery.js should include first..

Comment: Just place your header's js in header.php and footer's js in footer.php .

Comment: thanks @Sarath. problem has been solved after loading jquery file before other js files that too only in header.php

Answer (score 0):

- first make sure that you are actually calling all js files correctly (i.e. using firebug).
- which javascript functions are not working exactly?
  is it a jquery function like $('').click() ?
  in that case You need to use event delegation to attach events for dynamically loaded elements.
- have you calles the function inside a Jquery function like this (which won't work):

  $(document).ready(function() {`function test()}`);
- is there any Ajax in your code?
- could you show us your code to get an better idea about your problem :)